# RHEL7: Why does 'nmcli conn show' & 'ip addr show' display different connections?

Tags: networking, rhel, devices, networkmanager, network-interface

My 'nmcli conn show' & /'etc/sysconfig/network-scripts' config files don't match up, showing just one connection/devices of each:

```
[root@ciroc network-scripts]# ls |grep ifcfg
ifcfg-enp0s3
ifcfg-lo
[root@ciroc network-scripts]# nmcli conn show
NAME                UUID                                  TYPE            DEVICE 
Wired connection 1  644049a4-bf5c-41ce-aa77-477b567df2e3  802-3-ethernet  enp0s8
```

However, when I do 'ip addr show' it shows two connections/devices. I do indeed have two devices set up on this VM.

```
[root@ciroc network-scripts]# ip addr show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:2a:8b:80 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.56.112/24 brd 192.168.56.255 scope global enp0s3
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe2a:8b80/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: enp0s8: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:6b:72:ba brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.2.4/24 brd 10.0.2.255 scope global dynamic enp0s8
       valid_lft 779sec preferred_lft 779sec
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe6b:72ba/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Taking a look at the routes:

```
[root@ciroc network-scripts]# ip route show
default via 10.0.2.1 dev enp0s8  proto static  metric 1024 
10.0.2.0/24 dev enp0s8  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.2.4 
169.254.0.0/16 dev enp0s3  scope link  metric 1002 
192.168.56.0/24 dev enp0s3  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.56.112
```

Why is enp0s3 missing from the nmcli? and enp0s8 missing from the network-scripts part?

Comment: check out the files `ifcfg-enp0s3` e `ifcfg-enp0s8` inside `etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/`. Both have the parameter `NM_CONTROLLED=yes` ?

Comment: As mentioned in the first part of my post, 'ifcfg-enp0s8' file is missing. I never deleted it, this is a fresh install.

Comment: Well, the default behavior of the parameter `NM_CONTROLLED=` is to set the `no` value. Try to create this file copying from the other interface, and removing `UUID` `HWADDR` and renaming the interface `NAME` parameter...

Answer (score 3):

enp0s3 is managed by **system scripts** under etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/; i.e. that network will be configured on boot even if NetworkManager isn't running. enp0s8 is not managed by system scripts (as there's no network script to set it up).

enp0s8 instead is managed by **NetworkManager**; i.e. that network will be configured by NetworkManager once NetworkManager starts. *nmcli* only shows the connections managed by NetworkManager, and NetworkManager itself makes sure it doesn't interfere with other network interfaces configured via network scripts. So basically NetworkManager (and therefore *nmcli*) will ignore enp0s3.

*ip addr* and *ip route* both talk to the **kernel** asking which interfaces and routes are available in the system. The kernel doesn't care if these are managed via system scripts or NetworkManager.

Comment: How to know if the interface is managed by NetworkManager?

Comment: @KymoWang try `nmcli device status` or `nmcli d` for short